# OpenVPN connects but gets invalid IP on Tap Device

Tags: openvpn

I have a WinXP SP2 box trying to connect on a OpenVPN server and getting the following errors:

```
    Tue May 14 11:29:52 2013 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of
    192.168.5.6/255.255.248.0 on interface {48B4760C-5A76-4F9E-9140-FB73DF819E2A} [DHCP-serv: 192.168.0.0, lease-time: 31536000]
    Tue May 14 11:29:52 2013 Successful ARP Flush on interface [2] {48B4760C-5A76-4F9E-9140-FB73DF819E2A}
    Tue May 14 11:29:57 2013 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
    Tue May 14 11:29:57 2013 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
    Tue May 14 11:30:00 2013 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
    Tue May 14 11:30:00 2013 Route: Waiting for TUN/TAP interface to come up...
    Tue May 14 11:30:01 2013 TEST ROUTES: 0/0 succeeded len=1 ret=0 a=0 u/d=down
```

Fireall and Antivirus are already turned off.

Here's my client config:

```
client
float
dev tap
proto udp
remote xxxx 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca endian-001.pem
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: Are you running the OpenVPN client with administrative privileges?  You'll need that to set routes.

Comment: Yes full administrative privileges.

Comment: Did the OpenVPN Network Adapter actually get installed?  If you go to  'Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections' do you see a device with 'Device Name' of `TAP Windows Adapter V9`?

Answer (score 2):

If you post your server.conf it will greatly assist others in helping.

Firstly, the errors you are getting are specifically about the ROUTES being pushed, not necessarily the IP assignment. The logs show that it's trying to get an IP, so I assume that's configured on the server, but it doesn't look like routes are. I'll go over both items...

**IP Assignment:**

To define what range of IP addresses you get from the OpenVPN server, you set it at the "server" item in your **server.conf** and, in my working config, defined the topology as "subnet":

Example:

```
topology subnet
server 10.10.18.0 255.255.255.0
```

In the above example, the Subnet for clients will be 10.10.18.0/24

It looks like, from your log you are pushing a subnet (192.168.5.6/255.255.248.0) so that may already be configured properly.

**Routes:**

The errors are specifically complaining about the routes.

Your log shows 0 out of 0 total routes were successful, so it sounds like it doesn't even have any routes to push too.

```
0/0 succeeded
```

In the server config file you utilize the `push` item to push out routes to the clients. Ensure you have the routes defined in your **server.conf**.

Here is an example:

```
push "route 10.10.2.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.10.3.0 255.255.255.0"
```

If you provided your server config it would really help out.

**Summary:**
Ensure your server.conf is configured to assign addresses properly, and it's configured to push your desired routes.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the static routes to your .conf file. Example:

```
server 10.25.6.0 255.255.255.192
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/client-config
push "route 10.25.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.25.4.4"
```

A full .conf looks like:

```
local 10.25.50.2
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert vpn01.crt
key vpn01.key
dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.25.50.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/client-config
push "route 10.25.0.0 255.255.0.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.25.25.25."
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
inactive 900
```

Where /etc/openvpn/client-config is the folder of client assigned static IPs:

> Example: sudo cat /etc/openvpn/client-config/user2
>
> > ifconfig-push 10.101.6.22 255.255.255.0